# Reading CSV file with PHP: first item is always enclosed by double quotes

Tags: php, csv

I'm reading a CSV file, plain and simple:

```
$handle = fopen( 'example.csv', 'r' );
$lines = [];
while( true )
{
    $data = fgetcsv( $handle );
    if( $data === false )
    {
        break;
    }
    $lines[] = $data;
}
fclose( $handle );

$header = $lines[0];
var_export( $header );
echo "\n";
exit(0);
```

Everything works fine except that when the **first item** of the **first line** is parsed, text delimiter double quotes `"` (if present) are not stripped away but returned in the parsed data.

Let's see:

**CSV File**

```
"ID","Name","Surname"
"a1","John","Doe"
...
```

**Output of the code above**

```
array (
  0 => '"ID"',
  1 => 'Name',
  2 => 'Surname' )
```

**Why `"ID"` has double quotes around it?**

---

On the second line this doesn't happen:

```
var_export( $lines[1] );
```

returns

```
array (
  0 => 'a1',
  1 => 'John',
  2 => 'Doe' )
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of the csv file please

Comment: @RiggsFolly they are in the question under **CSV**

Comment: Thats a real 2 rows from the file?

Comment: May be worth checking for a BOM, try using `var_dump()` instead of `var_export()`.

Comment: @NigelRen you're right. There is a BOM byte at the beginning! Thank you!